Cannot test method in service logic
I want to test this method:
@Override
public GenreResponse fetchGenreById(Long genreId) {
    return convertGenreToGenreResponse(findGenreEntityByGenreId(genreId));
}

private GenreResponse convertGenreToGenreResponse(Genre genre) {
    return modelMapper.map(genre, GenreResponse.class);
}

private Genre findGenreEntityByGenreId(long genreId) {
    return genreRepository.findByGenreId(genreId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException("Genre with " + genreId + " id not found!"));
}

I wrote a test for this method, but it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why.
This is my test:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GenreCrudServiceTest {

@Mock
private ModelMapper mockModelMapper;

@Mock
private GenreRepository mockGenreRepository;

private GenreCrudService genreCrudService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

    genreCrudService = new GenreCrudServiceImpl(mockModelMapper, mockGenreRepository);
}

@Test
public void GenreCrudService_FetchGenreById_ReturnsGenreResponse() {
    // Arrange
    long genreId = 1;

    Genre genre = Genre.builder()
        .genreId(genreId)
        .title("testTitle")
        .build();

    Mockito.when(mockGenreRepository.findByGenreId(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(genre));

    // Act
    GenreResponse genreResponse = genreCrudService.fetchGenreById(genreId);

    // Assert
    Assertions.assertThat(genreResponse).isNotNull();
}

But my test doesn't work, it gives me an error:
Expecting actual not to be null
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual not to be null

The error occurs on this line:
Assertions.assertThat(genreResponse).isNotNull();

I can't figure out why I'm getting null returned, because here I've defined:
Mockito.when(mockGenreRepository.findByGenreId(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(genre));

that when searching for a genre by id, a specific Genre will be returned, and further method should convert it to GenreResponse

It returns null because your modelMapper is a mock and you didn't set the behaviour of it.
So, the fetchGenreById service method actually returns what modelMapper.map returns. And, if modelMapper is a mock, then it doesn't matter whether mockGenreRepository.findByGenreId returns null or Optional.of(genre), as long as it doesn't throw any exceptions. In the end you need to configure modelMapper:
when(mockModelMapper.map(any(), any(GenreResponse.class))).thenReturn(someGenreResponse);



And do note that such a test becomes useless pretty quickly if the mapper is mocked. It's not testing much, besides that the last method call returns the stubbed value. You would then have to verify the call and check if it received the expected arguments. Better to use a real ModelMapper instance that maps your database response to the response object. That way, your tests become a lot more robust

I agree that in such case it makes sense to use a real ModelMapper

You need to mock the map method of ModelMapper so that it returns a non-null object as shown below:
Mockito.when(mockModelMapper.map(genre, GenreResponse.class)).thenReturn(new GenreResponse());

